# wxWidgets - How to embed .ico and .png images and use to paint toolbar items

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I want to create toolbar items and paint them from images in program memory rather than from files on disk. I would prefer to embed the images using a resource file (.rc), but if I need to roll my own somehow that's okay too.

The image files are .ico and .png.

Assuming I can use stuff from the .rc file, how do I complete this code?

```
void MyFrame::AddToolBarItem(int ID, wxSize sz, const char* file, const char* short_help, const char *long_help) {
    const char *end = file+strlen(file);
    const char *dot = std::find(file, end, '.');
    if(dot != end) {
        // It's an external file, with an extention, like .ico or .png
        wxImage im(file);
        im.Rescale(sz.x, sz.y, wxIMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        wxBitmap bmp(im);
        my_tool_bar->AddTool(ID, short_help, bmp, long_help);
    } else {
        // It's a resource
        // What now, StackOverflow???
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, I'll make it easier. Forget about Rescale. I can do that with Gimp picture editor. Assume the images are the right size. You may also assume they are .ico or whatever format is convenient to wxWidgets.

EDIT 2: I am accepting an answer, but I have decided it is best just to embed the image "by hand", avoiding the .rc concept altogether. I wrote a little program to create a .cpp file with static initializers, but one can find them on the net. When compiled into the program, the .cpp file creates a copy of the image file in read-only memory. The .rc file is a Windows-specific thing, so it would be a good idea to avoid using it for custom icons and cursors, for portability. However, it does make sense to have a .rc file in the MS project that contains only the line "#include <wx/msw/wx.rc>" That will give access to some stock cursors and so forth that are available by default on other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for loading PNG from resources in wx itself but it's easy to do it in your code, see http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Embedding_PNG_Images#Embedding_PNG_images_into_Windows_rc_file

Answer (score 2):

The [Bitmaps and Icons overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_bitmap.html) gives a pretty good explanation of this. Basically once you have embedded the resource in your .rc file all you need to do is:

```
wxBitmap bmp(wxBITMAP(bmpnameinrcfile));
```

similarly for ico

```
wxIcon icon(wxICON(iconameinrcfile));
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work. A stack-trace dialog pops up and the images do not load. I had already hit on an almost-solution, namely, wxBitmap bmp(wxString(file), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO_RESOURCE); There was a problem with that also - a scary stacktrace dialog that I later discovered was a warning. But it was warning about something in the wxWidgets code, not anything dubious that I had done. I modified the code in the core project, image.cpp, recompiled wxWidgets, and submitted a bug-ticket, http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14643